# Unable to resolve host on API call for HTTP POST on Android

Tags: android, rest, azure, http-post

The URL is correct and I have tried a sample of the same from python so I don't think that URL is an issue.
I guess there's something to do with the syntax.
I have added the following in the Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
```

This should ensure that my app has internet access and it indeed has as the other parts work well/

Here is the logic where I get an error:

```
try {
                URL url = new URL("https://centralinda.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/face/v1.0/verify");//?faceId1=" + face1 + "&faceId2=" + face2);
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                urlConnection.setRequestProperty("Ocp-Apim-Subscription-Key", "**");
                JSONObject input   = new JSONObject();
                input.put("faceId1",face1);
                input.put("faceId2",face2);
                Log.v("beforereq","beforereq");
                OutputStreamWriter wr= new OutputStreamWriter(urlConnection.getOutputStream());
                wr.write(input.toString());
                wr.flush();
                Log.v("calling123","calling");
                try {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(urlConnection.getInputStream()));
                    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                    String line;
                    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
                    }
                    bufferedReader.close();
                    getting = stringBuilder.toString();
                    Log.v("Gettinganswer", getting);
                    return  getting;
                } finally {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                Log.e("ERROR", e.getMessage(), e);
                return null;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

> >ping centralinda.api.cognitive.microsoft.com
>
> Ping request could not find host centralinda.api.cognitive.microsoft.com. Please check the name and try again.

centralinda.api.cognitive.microsoft.com is not a valid hostname. It is not registered with DNS.

Answer (score 0):

Unable to resolve host only shows when there is a problem with the url, have you tried calling the api in Postman?